# Sub-theme of a sub-theme

Tags: theming

If you have a sub-theme of a sub-theme...

- Sub-theme a
- Sub-theme b (base theme = Sub-theme a)

Ideally, what I want to do is have the default theme as 'Sub theme a' and just introduce some minor theming and processing in 'Sub theme b'. Reason being, there are lots of versions of this site being deployed and some minor fixes are required that can be thrown away at the click of a button i.e. remove Sub-theme b.

Google has not been helpful in this instance ;-)

**If both themes are enabled and sub-theme a is the default, how do I get sub-theme b to work? (because its not working i.e. I have added a stylesheet in the .info file and its not being added. If I make sub-theme b default then Sub-theme a doesnt work)**

Comment: What is effective is the default theme. Either Sub-theme a or Sub-theme b can be the default theme at any time. No need to remove anything.

Comment: Sorry, I have made an edit because you made me realise I was asking this correctly, cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? If you set it as your theme in your profile, or with theme switcher, it fails to render? Or what are your expectations and your results?

Comment: Ive defined a stylesheet with sub-theme b .info file and its not being added as expected. Both themes a and b are enabled and sub-theme a is default.

Comment: @AlexGill so, it works as designed. Sub-theme b is enabled, but no one is *using* it, so it's CSS is never used. Now, if user will switch to b (enabled only means he can switch to it, nothing more!), b's CSS will work. That's all to it. Now, if b is default and is indeed subtheme of a, everything in a should work OK. How is it not working for you then?

Comment: Ok, so ideally if sub-theme b uses sub-theme a as a base, it should inherit everything from sub-theme a?

Comment: Exactly, that's how it is supposed to work. If b is subtheme of a, and a is a subtheme of x, then when using b, you should have everything from x, overridden by things from a, overridden by things from b. Works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *always* start with a base-theme.  Let us call this **Theme A**.  If you introduce a sub-theme (e.g. **Theme B** as a sub-theme of **Theme A**), it inherits everything from **Theme A**.  You can introduce minor (or major) tweaks in **Theme B**.

If you set **Theme B** as the default, then you get **Theme A** + **Theme B**.

If you set **Theme A** as the default, then you get **Theme A** (with nothing from **Theme B**).

In other words, if you've set **Theme A** as the default, then **Theme B** is not *supposed* to work.   To get **Theme B** to "work", you *must* set **Theme B** as the default.

This also works if you cascade with more sub-themes.

For instance, if you introduce another sub-theme (e.g. **Theme C** as a sub-theme of **Theme B**), it inherits everything from **Theme A** and **Theme B**. You can then introduce minor (or major) tweaks in **Theme C**.

If you set **Theme C** as the default, then you get **Theme A** + **Theme B**  + **Theme C**.

A theme need to be enabled to be set as default, but works fine as an inherited theme even when it is not enabled.